# Installing PowerShell module persistently for all users

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-module

I'm installing a PowerShell module via [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) onto a number of different servers. For testing purposes, I went with the guidance of Microsoft's documentation for [installing PowerShell Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module).

This worked fine, but as the documentation stated, my changes would be visible only for the current session. That is, if I were to do the following:

```
$modulePath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
# More practically, this would be some logic to install only if not present
$modulePath += ";C:\CustomModules"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $modulePath, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

When running this installer automatically on tentacle servers, future PowerShell sessions do not appear to see the newly installed modules.

How can I install a PowerShell module in a profile agnostic way so that every PowerShell session started can see it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PowerShell can only "see" modules installed in one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`. Otherwise you'll have to import the module with its full path.

To make a new module visible to all users you basically have two options:

1. Install the module to the default system-wide module directory (`C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`).
2. Modify the system environment so that `PSModulePath` variable already contains your custom module directory (e.g. via a [group policy preference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772047.aspx)).

The latter will only become effective for PowerShell sessions started after the modification was made, though.

Comment: PowerShell 3.0 and higher auto load the modules it can find with the method above. So no need to import the modules manually or have them imported in a profile.

Comment: You'd rather use the 2nd option, as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx recomends not to install user's modules in
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
"This location is reserved for modules that ship with Windows. Do not install modules to this location."

Answer (score 2):

This profile applies to all users and all shells.

```
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
```

Comment: the profile in your article link only applies 'per user', the one above is machine-wide.

Comment: Can I be assured that this will run, even if the shell is opened with `-NoProfile`?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that. I have to assume that the module will be loaded in a `-NoProfile` environment.

Answer (score 1):

After taking the steps you spelled out in your question (which I think is the general way to go), I found two ways to get the new module source recognized by Powershell:

- Restart the machine. (Works every time.)
- Reset the `PSModulePath` in each open session.

  ```
  $env:PSModulePath=[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")
  ```

  I found this was necessary to run in both normal and elevated prompts to get this to work without restarting in each type of prompt. (See also the conversation @ [Topic: PSModulePath](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/psmodulepath/).)