# 'Get-windowsfeature' is not recognized after installing backup functions

Tags: powershell

I am trying to check the install backup functions and commandline tools are enabled or not.

I've executed `Import-ServerManager` and ran the necessary commands to enable backup functions, once done I check them:

```
$BackupFunction = Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Backup"}
$BackupTools = Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Backup-Tools"}
if($BackupFunction.Installed -and $BackupTools.Installed -eq "True")
```

The code is returning `True` with same PowerShell window.

But if I close and open a new Powershell then checking again it returns

> The term 'Get-WindowFeature' is not recognized..

Comment: Check the scope of the `Import-Module ServerManager`. By default, the `Import-Module` cmdlet adds modules to the current session. That means, once, you close the session, the module is lost. Please check and confirm if you are doing the same?

Comment: Thanks Vivek I found the scope of the Import-Module it is survey only current session. we can add to powershell profile to use all sessions but do we have any other command or way to fix this.please advise.

Comment: "Import-Module servermanager -force",
"Add-WindowsFeature -Name Backup-Features -includeAllSubFeature",
"Add-PSSnapin -Name Windows.ServerBackup"

this is commands I need use all the session globally kindly give some suggestion.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885398/installing-powershell-module-persistently-for-all-users) link. Might solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks but can we add "Add-WindowsFeature -Name Backup-Features -IncludeAllSubFeature" to module ? if not how could i add becasue i have created parts for installbackup and confirmbackup then i calling the parts into component with precheck(if backup function is not installled then install) postcheck (checking backup function is installed or not) i am using start-job for timeout script execution. i have created the profile for this but not working as its creating new job for each execution. this is how i stuck please give some betterment i will try mean time with modules.

Comment: I would suggest you to add `Add-WindowsFeature -Name Backup-Features -IncludeAllSubFeature` as a function and create a `.psm1` file. You can then,  follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx) msdn documentation and install the module. After, this is done, your module will then be available for all user sessions.